# How to add a Kernel from another distro

Tags: kernel, 15.04, surface

I've been using archlinux with a patched kernel on my surface pro 3.
I switched to ubuntu now and want to use the kernel that includes all the patches from arch with ubuntu.
What is the best way to add the Kernel?
Can I simply copy the vmlinuz and initramfs and update-grub?

I copied the files and updated grub, which worked fine.
But when I boot the new Kernel I get a Kernel panic:
`Unable to mount root filesystem`.[image]

The Kernel [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/182095/can-i-use-a-kernel-package-from-another-distro) was provided precompiled with with `/usr` and `/lib` as a `.tar.gz` archive.
The Kernel package I used does not provide that,it just contains the patches, so I can't justcopy `/usr` and `/lib` from the archive.

I could copy them from my arch distribution running this Kernel, but what specific directories would I have to copy, the whole `/usr` and `/lib`?

Comment: In short - yes, in long - yes, but you probably may have a problems with loading modules and other things. Try to just copy these files in boot directory and boot manualy from grub CLI, it's interesting experiment. But I don't think ubuntu have old kernel without patches, try to search kernel ppa for vivid (there is 4.0RC)

Comment: Thanks I will try it later. Most patches for the surface pro 3 are unfourtunatley not in the mainline kernel yet so you need to add them yourself.

Comment: is this patched kernel available to download?

Comment: I have compiled it myself, but there is one in the [AUR](https://aur.archlinux.org/packages/linux-surfacepro3).

Comment: Booting the kernel results in a Kernel panic.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Can I use a kernel package from another distro?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/182095/can-i-use-a-kernel-package-from-another-distro)

Comment: yes, as I pointed out below (and by karel above), you could try copying other important folders as well.

Comment: I edited the question with more information.

Comment: Still not sure what data to copy  from `/usr` and `/lib`. Recompiling the kernel on ubuntu worked fine. But a solution would be great so I don't have to compile the Kernel twice every time.

Answer (score 0):

simply copying the vmlinuz and initramfs and `update-grub` might work, but you might also need `lib` and `usr`. There is an interesting [post](https://askubuntu.com/questions/182095/can-i-use-a-kernel-package-from-another-distro) that shows it is possible to use arch kernals in ubuntu.